# How to join to a statement with a row_number() function in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I a SQL with a row_number() function, and I would like to join on additional tables to get the fields below.  How would I accomplish this?

Desired fields:

```
EMPLOYEE.EMPLID 
  EMPLOYEE.JOBTITLE
  NAME.FIRST_NAME
  NAME.LAST_NAME
  LOCATION.ADDRESS
  PROFESSIONAL_NAME.PROF_NAME
```

Beginning SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT EMPLOYEE.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLID ORDER BY 
        PRIM_ROLE_IND DESC, EMPL_RCD ASC) as RN
        FROM EMPLOYEE
        WHERE JOB_INDICATOR = 'P'
    ) dt
WHERE RN = 1
```

When I try to add a left join at the end, I get an error that says "EMPLOYEE"."EMLID" invalid identifier.

What I'm trying:

```
SELECT 
  EMPLOYEE.EMPLID, 
  EMPLOYEE.JOBTITLE,
  NAME.FIRST_NAME, 
  NAME.LAST_NAME, 
  LOCATION.ADDRESS,
  PROFESSIONAL_NAME.PROF_NAME 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT EMPLOYEE.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLID ORDER BY 
        PRIM_ROLE_IND DESC, EMPL_RCD ASC) as RN
        FROM EMPLOYEE
        WHERE JOB_INDICATOR = 'P'
    ) 
    
    LEFT JOIN NAME ON EMPLOYEE.EMPLID = NAME.EMPLID 
WHERE 
  RN = 1
  AND
  NAME.EFFDT = (
    SELECT 
      MAX (NAME2.EFFDT) 
    FROM 
      NAME NAME2 
    WHERE 
      NAME2.EMPLID = NAME.EMPLID 
      AND NAME.NAME_TYPE = 'PRI'
  )  
  AND EMPLOYEE.JOB_INDICATOR = 'P'
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to alias your table

```
...
(
    SELECT EMPLOYEE.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLID ORDER BY 
    PRIM_ROLE_IND DESC, EMPL_RCD ASC) as RN
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE JOB_INDICATOR = 'P'
) temp_employee --add this
LEFT JOIN NAME ON temp_employee.EMPLID = NAME.EMPLID 
...
```

When you create your new table with row_number() in an inner select you essentially create a new table.  You need to `alias` or name this table and then refer to that alias.  In the above your `from` is the inner select, not the EMPLOYEE table.  See below for simplified example.

```
select newtable.field from (select field from mytable) newtable
```